# checkbox value id not getting

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I tried to store my checkbox value ID to database but i am getting error count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in.
please anyone to help me figure out my problem this is what I am trying to

The HTML:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1[ ]" value="<?php echo $rows['AMOUNT'] .' - '. $rows['ID'] .' ';?>">&nbsp<?php echo $rows['DESCRIPTION'];?></input>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
    
    $checkbox = $_POST['chk1'];
    $check = implode(", AND ", $checkbox);
    $value = explode(", AND ", $check);
    $AMOUNT = trim($value[0]);
    $FEE_ID = trim($value[1]);
    
for($i=0;$i<count($FEE_ID);$i++){
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO fee_checked (FEE_ID) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i",  $FEE_ID[$i]);
$stmt->execute();
}
}
?>
```

Please Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

Ok so after the some comments below I am now looking at:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Save'])) {
        $check = implode(", AND ",$_POST['chk1']);
        $value = explode(", AND ", $check);
   for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++) {
    print_r($value[$i]);
}
}
?>
```

looks like this when print_r($value[$i]):

8000 - 9 3000 - 10 500 - 11

so I want to store [ID's] Values of 9,10,11 to table.

Comment: Only checked boxes are submitted. You probably didn't check any of them.

Comment: `</input>` is invalid HTML, btw.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. You implode only to immediately explode on the same value, ending up with the same array you started with.

Comment: change the input attr from name="chk1[ ]"  to name="chk1"

Comment: And then you actually try to count a string value, because that's what `$FEE_ID` will be.

Comment: Debugging is a crucial skill in the world of programming. Learn the [basics](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/), because you really need to inspect what your variables are holding.

Comment: @Jwan i am trying to get multiple values of checkbox Id, so I used chk1[ ]. thank you.

Comment: **@EI_Vanja** with out implode and explode working any error. but storing amount value.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense - you have multiple checkboxes, but you're expecting to get multiple values from a single checkbox value. I can only assume what you're trying to do (`foreach` on `$_POST['chk1']` and then `explode` each value on `' - '`, because that's how you separate your two values in the checkbox).

Comment: @EI_Vanja Sorry to say its not single checkbox, that checkbox values are multiple and also check boxes also multiple. just I want to get second ['ID'] values. is there any possible to separate two values of the checkbox. thank you for responding here

Comment: Hi friends thank you for your suggestions. I edited my question after some comments  I am getting result with out errors. i am getting two values but i want to store second value to table. please suggest me about this issue, Once again thank you all who given some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your updated code in your question:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Save'])) {
  if(isset($_POST['chk1'])) {
    $value = $_POST['chk1'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++) {
        $val = explode("-", $value[$i]);
        $AMOUNT = trim($val[0]);
        $FEE_ID = trim($val[1]);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO fee_checked (FEE_ID) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("i",  $FEE_ID);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
  }
}
?>
```

As you are getting values in 8000 - 9 3000 - 10 500 - 11. These values will be `explode()` with `-`to get amount and Id's values.

Edit: More, if no checkbox is checked the `$_POST['chk1']` will not be there. So you have to add condition for it as well.

Comment: **Thanking You** so much Its Working, I just changed $stmt->bind_param("i",  $FEE_ID[$i]); into $stmt->bind_param("i",  $FEE_ID); once again thank you.

Comment: `$value` will be the same as `$_POST['chk1']`. The `implode` and `explode` calls are absolutely unnecessary.